# Rails passing params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, parameters

I feel like I'm missing a fundamentally easier way to do this; either way, I don't appear to have the syntax for array figured out. Trying to stuff things into the params array. Any help is appreciated.

```
@user = User.find(params[:user][:id])

array_of_match_information = Array.new
array_of_match_information[mentee] = @user.id
array_of_match_information[mentor] = self.id
array_of_match_information[status] = "Pending"    

@match = Match.new(params[:array_of_match_information])
```

Thanks.

Comment: `:mentee`, `:mentor`, `:status`

Comment: Because you should work with a Hash, not with an Array

Comment: Why are you monkeying with `params`?

Comment: @apneadiving sorry, I'm still learning the syntax - what would this look like as a Hash?

Comment: @monadic I'm trying to send Match.new three values, and I assumed (inaccurately, I'm thinking?) that I needed to put them in the params array. is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_of_match_information = Hash.new
array_of_match_information[:mentee] = @user.id
array_of_match_information[:mentor] = self.id
array_of_match_information[:status] = "Pending"
```

EDIT

`Hash` is a key/value storage, like you intend to do.

`mentee` is a key that will be associated to a value `@user_id`

Array don't organize data (unless you consider the position in the Array is known and meaningful)

EDIT2:

And correct this:

```
@match = Match.new(array_of_match_information)
```

EDIT3:

I encourage you to have a look at http://railsforzombies.org, it seems you need a good tutorial.

Actually, building an app when you're learning could be hazardous because when you don't know basic architecture, you end up overcoding unmaintainable code.

For instance, your line:

```
    array_of_match_information[:mentor] = self.id
```

seems really weird.

Comment: Hmm. Well that certainly worked (ie, didn't throw an exception), thanks - but it didn't pass the values to Match.new as I expected it would.

Comment: I assumed my controller code would pick this up: `def new
    @match = Match.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @match }
    end
  end`

Comment: AWESOME.Thanks for your patience - this syntax is tricky to learn, coming from php - that worked perfectly.

Comment: You really don't need that `array_of_match_information` hash at all. Just wrap it with {} and pass it to the method: Match.new({ :mentor => ..., :mentee => ..., ...})

Comment: @apneadiving The app isn't really important (it's a hobby, not a client) - I figured assigning myself something to do would be the best way to learn :)

Comment: @Jon, ok got it, so you're right, it's perfect to learn while doing but be sure to know the basics!

Comment: Still it's always better to learn and apply the best practices. And "Don't Repeat Yourself" is what you're gonna hear a lot working with Rails.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you're trying to implement a basic social network functionality. If I'm right, you should use associations. It would look something like this (I don't know the specifics of your mentor-mentee relation, so I suppose it's a many-to-many relationship):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :matches
  has_many :mentors, :through => :match
  has_many :mentees, :through => :match
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :mentor, :class_name => 'User'
  belong_to :mentee, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Then, in your controller you could do this:

```
class matches_controller < ApplicationController

  def create
    # current_user is a Devise helper method 
    # which simply returns the current_user through sessions. 
    # You can do it yourself.

    Match.create({ :mentee => @user, :mentor => current_user }) 
    # "pending" status could be set up as a default value in your DB migration
  end

end
```

But as I said, that's just a sample of code. I can't guarantee that it will work or suit your applications.

And you totally should check out [this book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do but at the very least, you should be using symbols when you set the 3 values:

```
array_of_match_information[:mentee] = @user.id
array_of_match_information[:mentor] = self.id
array_of_match_information[:status] = "Pending"
```

edit:

You should actually be doing this:

```
match_information = {}
match_information[:mentee] = @user.id
match_information[:mentor] = self.id
match_information[:status] = "Pending"
```

Without seeing your model, it's hard for me to know, but I suspect it actually wants the hash, not an array.

Comment: That's closer, of course :)   But I still get this exception:  **Symbol as array index**

Comment: oh, yeah, you need a hash. my mistake. I didn't read correctly.